# Qt5 Beta - can't find serviceframework.pro

Tags: c++, linux, qt, installation, qml

I am trying to install Qt5 - Beta on Ubuntu i386.
http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt_5.0

I run the commands:

```
./configure -prefix $PWD/qtbase -opensource -nomake tests
make
```

and also tried

```
./configure -prefix $PWD/qtbase -opensource -nomake tests
./build -j 4
```

And I am having respectively the following errors:

```
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.0/qtbase/examples'
cd serviceframework/ && /home/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.0/qtbase/bin/qmake  /home/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.0/qtbase/examples/serviceframework   /serviceframework.pro -spec /home/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.0/qtbase/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o Makefile
Cannot find file: /home/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.0/qtbase/examples/serviceframework/serviceframework.pro.
make[2]: *** [serviceframework/Makefile] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.0/qtbase/examples'
make[1]: *** [sub-examples-make_default-ordered] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.0/qtbase'
make: *** [module-qtbase-make_default] Error 2
```

and

```
Cannot find file: /home/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.0/qtbase/examples/serviceframework/serviceframework.pro.
make[1]: *** [serviceframework/Makefile] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Cannot find file: /home/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.0/qtbase/examples/publishsubscribe/publishsubscribe.pro.
make[1]: *** [publishsubscribe/Makefile] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.0/qtbase/examples'
make: *** [sub-examples-make_default-ordered] Error 2
cd qtbase && make -j 4 exited with status 512 at ./build line 64
    Qt::Build::exe('Qt::Build=HASH(0x8dae8b8)', 'cd qtbase && make -j 4') called at ./build line 114
    Qt::Build::exeLowPriv('Qt::Build=HASH(0x8dae8b8)', 'cd qtbase && make -j 4') called at ./build line 377
    Qt::Build::build_project('Qt::Build=HASH(0x8dae8b8)', 'qtbase') called at ./build line 408
    Qt::Build::build_qt('Qt::Build=HASH(0x8dae8b8)') called at ./build line 437
    Qt::Build::run('Qt::Build=HASH(0x8dae8b8)') called at ./build line 446
'cd qtbase && make -j 4' failed: 512 at ./build line 377.
```

All right, I also tried on Windows 8. Did similar approach:

```
 set PATH=%PATH%;%CD%\qtbase\bin;
 configure -prefix %CD%\qtbase -opensource -nomake tests
 mingw32-make
```

and

```
 set PATH=%PATH%;%CD%\qtbase\bin;
 configure -prefix %CD%\qtbase -opensource -nomake tests
 perl build
```

Having the respectively following errors:

```
 codecs\qtextcodec.cpp: In function 'void setup()':
 codecs\qtextcodec.cpp:288:16: error: expected type-specifier before 'QIconvCodec
 '
codecs\qtextcodec.cpp:288:16: error: expected ';' before 'QIconvCodec'
mingw32-make[4]: *** [tmp/obj/debug_shared/qtextcodec.o] Error 1
mingw32-make[4]: Leaving directory `C:/2_install/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.
0.0-beta1/qtbase/src/corelib'
mingw32-make[3]: *** [debug-all] Error 2
mingw32-make[3]: Leaving directory `C:/2_install/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.
0.0-beta1/qtbase/src/corelib'
mingw32-make[2]: *** [sub-corelib-make_first] Error 2
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory `C:/2_install/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.
0.0-beta1/qtbase/src'
mingw32-make[1]: *** [sub-src-make_first] Error 2
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory `C:/2_install/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.
0.0-beta1/qtbase'
mingw32-make: *** [module-qtbase-make_first] Error 2
```

and

```
codecs\qtextcodec.cpp:288:16: error: expected ';' before 'QIconvCodec'
mingw32-make[3]: *** [tmp/obj/debug_shared/qtextcodec.o] Error 1
mingw32-make[3]: Leaving directory `C:/2_install/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.
0.0-beta1/qtbase/src/corelib'
mingw32-make[2]: *** [debug-all] Error 2
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory `C:/2_install/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.
0.0-beta1/qtbase/src/corelib'
mingw32-make[1]: *** [sub-corelib-make_first] Error 2
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory `C:/2_install/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.
0.0-beta1/qtbase/src'
mingw32-make: *** [sub-src-make_first] Error 2
'cd qtbase && "C:\MinGW\bin\mingw32-make.exe" ' failed: 512
Fatal failure building qtbase at build line 443.
    Qt::Build::build_project('Qt::Build=HASH(0x5a711c)', 'qtbase') called at
  build line 484
    Qt::Build::build_qt('Qt::Build=HASH(0x5a711c)') called at build line 544

    Qt::Build::run('Qt::Build=HASH(0x5a711c)') called at build line 553
```

So, apparently it is a bug in the package.

Some comments? Any suggestion is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of running the static binaries, built it from the source and most probably you will get this kind of weird error solved. I got similar problems and only solved after building it. Have a check here:

- [Building Qt 5 from Git](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building_Qt_5_from_Git)